# Error al compilar app en ionic 3

Tags: ionic, cordova

Quiero compilar mi proyecto pero me sale este error

> -no puede generar drawable-hdpiv4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png

intente reinstalando ionic y cordova "npm install -g ionic cordova"
pero sigue saliendo el mismo error

---

Cuento con:

```
        -Windows 10 x64
        -Ionic 3.12.0
        -Cordova 7.0.1
```

---

> [10:41:22]  lint finished in 9.27 s
>   × Running command - failed!
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

```
    (truncated) ...  UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
    :CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
    :CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :CordovaLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72531Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72531Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComAndroidSupportCustomtabs2531Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2531Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2531Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2531Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2531Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2531Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42531Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2531Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4260Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth1104Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase1104Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase1104Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement1104Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity1104Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks1104Library UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareOrgApacheCordovaCordovaLib623DebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
    :prepareDebugDependencies
    :compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
    :compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
    :generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
    :generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
    :generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
    :mergeDebugResources
    Error: Failed to crunch file S:\Proyecto JS\Proyectos\MAYLLU\Sesion Permanente\mayllu-mobile\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\11.0.4\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png into S:\Proyecto JS\Proyectos\MAYLLU\Sesion Permanente\mayllu-mobile\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png
    :mergeDebugResources FAILED

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 28.396 secs

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
    > Error: Failed to crunch file S:\Proyecto JS\Proyectos\MAYLLU\Sesion Permanente\mayllu-mobile\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\11.0.4\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png into S:\Proyecto JS\Proyectos\MAYLLU\Sesion Permanente\mayllu-mobile\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
    > Error: Failed to crunch file S:\Proyecto JS\Proyectos\MAYLLU\Sesion Permanente\mayllu-mobile\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\11.0.4\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png into S:\Proyecto JS\Proyectos\MAYLLU\Sesion Permanente\mayllu-mobile\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: Como haces la ejecución de la app?

Comment: Al ejecutar con "ionic serve" funciona en el navegador sin problemas, pero al compilar "ionic cordova build android" sale ese error

Comment: Ok, puede ser debido a varios problemas... intenta

1.- La ruta del archivo es demasiado larga..
2.- El nombre del archivo es demasiado largo y también la ruta...
3.- Cambiaste la extensión de la imagen, es decir, de un archivo .jpg a un archivo .png

Comment: Acorte el nombre y cambie la extension sin resultados. Este mismo codigo en otra computadora funciona sin errores, en la mia vota ese error, formatee mi computadora hace 2 dias antes de hacerlo no tenia ese error.

Comment: No es nada mas cambiar la extensión, es hacerlo mediante algún programa de imagen, la ruta del proyecto la cambiaste a una mas corta? Prueba también quitando la carpeta de los archivos de imagen, cuando compiles te debe dar otro error, luego las vuelves a agregar y podría funcionar... Revisa este post de stackoverlow en ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764604/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-crunching-cruncher-png-fa

Comment: compilado satisfactorio, gracias

Comment: Deberias anotar como lo resolviste en una respuesta... Saludos!